# Rails 4 integration testing cannot find link

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am using rails 4 and capybara 2.1.0 and rspec 2.0 to develope a user registration model

here is the contents of my spec

```
visit register_path  
fill_in 'user[full_name]', with: "xxxx"
click_button 'Register'
expect(page).to find_link("Send hosting request")
```

on register form after clicking the register button i am creating a user and redirecting them to there page say user/1 on the user show template

here is the show template

```
  <div>
  <strong>Full Name</strong>
  <%= @user.own_profile.full_name %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to 'Send hosting request', root_path %>
```

but when i run the test i got error saying cannot find link

```
1) Register Page Create User
   Failure/Error: find_link("Send hosting request")
   Capybara::ElementNotFound:
    Unable to find link "Send hosting request"
 # ./spec/integration/register_page_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

i don't understand why this test is failing when i have the link on the user page

what can i do now

when i use page.has_content?('Send hosting request') it returns true

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
expect(page).to have_link("Send hosting request")
```

It should work...

I found this link useful http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/RSpecMatchers

Have swing

Comment: Thanks for your reply  when i try i got a different error  as follows `Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_link('Send hosting request')
expected #has_link?("Send hosting request") to return true, got false`